# React Drag and Drop not working - Component rendering twice with previous values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

Please find the below CodeSandbox link.

[Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dnd-form-builder-vx2s4)

1. Simple React DND form builder.
2. The values when dropped, gets rendered twice.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There seems to have errors in your online demo

Comment: @keikai: error fixed.